# Почему программа завершается аварийно?

Tags: c++, структуры

Ошибка возникает при поиске книг по автору. Сначала ввыводиться правильная информация, но по завершению цикла программа ломается.Скажите, пожалуйста, что не так.

```
   #include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct book {
    char bookname[70];
    char author[50];
    char publisher[20];
    char genre[20];

};


book EditBook(book* books);
book searchAuth(book* books);
void print_one(book exp);
void print_all(book* exp);


int main()
{
    book* BOOK;
    book books[10] = { {"Caroline","Neil","Bloomsbury","horror"},
        {"Alice","Neil","Bloomsbury","fantasy"},
        {"HarryPotter","Rowling","Bloomsbury","fantasy"},
        {"MartinEden","Martin Lee","NewDay","sci-fi"},
        {"SherlockHolmes","Sd","OldDay","detective"},
         {"C++","FF","HTEW","horror"},
        {"Python","Rer","Kwed","adventure"},
        {"Harry Grotter","Ann","Bloom","fantasy"},
        {"Mart","Scier","Toyota","sci-fi"},
        {"Sher","Sd","OldDay","psychology"},
    };
    int choice;
    bool isOn = true;
    enum opt { exit = 0, edit = 1, showAll = 2, sortAuth = 3, sortTitle = 4 };
    while (isOn) {
        cout << "\n\t\t" << "WELCOME!\n";
        cout << "(0)Exit (1)Edit (2)Show all books (3) Sort by author (4) Sort by title: ";
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        default:
            isOn = false;
            break;
        case edit:
            EditBook(books);
            break;
        case showAll:
            print_all(books);
            break;
        case sortAuth:
            searchAuth(books);
            break;
        case sortTitle:

            break;
        }

    }

}


void print_one(book exp)
{
    cout << "BOOK INFO:\n" << "\tTitle: " << exp.bookname << "\t\t" << "\tAuthor: " << exp.author << "\t\t" << " \tPublisher: " << exp.publisher;
    cout << "\t\t" << "\tGenre: " << exp.genre << endl;
}

void print_all(book* exp)
{
    cout << "Name:" << "\t\t" << "Author:" << "\t\t" << "Publisher:";
    cout << "\t" << "Genre:";
    cout << "\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        print_one(exp[i]);
}

book EditBook(book* BOOK) {
    char title[30];
    char newtitle[30];
    cout << "Enter search book title: \n";
    cin >> title;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(BOOK[i].bookname,title)==0) {
            cout << "Enter new title: \n";
            cin >> newtitle;
            *BOOK[i].bookname = *newtitle;
            return BOOK[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "No such book title\n";
    throw "";
}

book searchAuth(book* BOOK) {
    char Author[30];
    cout << "Enter search book author: \n";
    cin >> Author;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(BOOK[i].author, Author) == 0) {
            print_one(BOOK[i]);
        }
    }
    cout << "No such book title\n";
    throw "";
}
```

Comment: Ну у вас по завершению цикла стоит throw, так что совершенно логично ожидать, что он сработает

Comment: @andreymal спасибо. Как можно завершить функцию без throw?

Comment: Ну просто уберите throw да и всё, наверное?

Comment: Только имейте в виду, что если вы объявили, что ваша функция возвращает структуру `book` — вы тогда обязаны её вернуть. Или же измените объявление функции

Comment: Что за мания завершать функцию через `throw`?! Объясните, **зачем**?

Comment: @Harry Спонсор данного метода мой учитель в компьютерной академии 

Comment: OK, но какое-то же объяснение этому он дает?

Comment: @Harry Ох, если бы...

Answer (score 0):

Рабочая программа:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct book {
    char bookname[70];
    char author[50];
    char publisher[20];
    char genre[20];

};
    
book EditBook(book* books);
void searchAuth(book* books);
void print_one(book exp);
void print_all(book* exp);
void searchTitle(book* books);

int main()
{
    book* BOOK;
    book books[10] = { {"Caroline","Neil","Bloomsbury","horror"},
        {"Alice","Neil","Bloomsbury","fantasy"},
        {"HarryPotter","Rowling","Bloomsbury","fantasy"},
        {"MartinEden","Martin Lee","NewDay","sci-fi"},
        {"SherlockHolmes","Sd","OldDay","detective"},
         {"C++","FF","HTEW","horror"},
        {"Python","Rer","Kwed","adventure"},
        {"HarryGrotter","Ann","Bloom","fantasy"},
        {"Mart","Scier","Toyota","sci-fi"},
        {"Sher","Sd","OldDay","psychology"},
    };
    int choice;
    bool isOn = true;
    enum opt { exit = 0, edit = 1, showAll = 2, sortAuth = 3, sortTitle = 4 };
    while (isOn) {
        cout << "\n\t\t" << "WELCOME!\n";
        cout << "(0)Exit (1)Edit (2)Show all books (3) Sort by author (4) Sort by title: ";
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        default:
            isOn = false;
            break;
        case edit:
            EditBook(books);
            break;
        case showAll:
            print_all(books);
            break;
        case sortAuth:
            searchAuth(books);
            break;
        case sortTitle:
            searchTitle(books);
            break;
        }

    }

}

void print_one(book exp)
{
    cout << "BOOK INFO:\n" << "\tTitle: " << exp.bookname << "\t\t" << "\tAuthor: " << exp.author << "\t\t" << " \tPublisher: " << exp.publisher;
    cout << "\t\t" << "\tGenre: " << exp.genre << endl;
}

void print_all(book* exp)
{
    cout << "Name:" << "\t\t" << "Author:" << "\t\t" << "Publisher:";
    cout << "\t" << "Genre:";
    cout << "\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        print_one(exp[i]);
}

book EditBook(book* BOOK) {
    char title[30];
    char newtitle[30];
    cout << "Enter search book title: \n";
    cin >> title;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(BOOK[i].bookname,title)==0) {
            cout << "Enter new title: \n";
            cin >> newtitle;
            *BOOK[i].bookname = *newtitle;
            return BOOK[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "No such book title\n";
    throw "";
}

void searchAuth(book* BOOK) {
    char Author[30];
    cout << "Enter search book author: \n";
    cin >> Author;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(BOOK[i].author, Author) == 0) {
            print_one(BOOK[i]);
        }
    }
    
}
void searchTitle(book* BOOK) {
    char title[30];
    cout << "Enter search book title: \n";
    cin >> title;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(BOOK[i].bookname, title) == 0) {
            print_one(BOOK[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Молчу уж о `throw`... Но как вы считаете, это — `*BOOK[i].bookname = *newtitle;` — работает? Или по замыслу, вы только одну букву копируете?

Comment: @Harry А как заставить это недоразумение работать?

Comment: Я только могу сказать, как делал бы я, но в моем варианте никаких `throw` нет, так что не уверен, что это подойдет... Да и я бы использовал `string`, не массив, а `vector`, не забивал бы 10 как размер, да и названия у вас должны быть только из одного слова... Но я же не знаю, что можно исправлять, а что в ТЗ. А без точного ТЗ ответ один - ХЗ...

Comment: @Harry спасибо за попытку) К сожалению, vector ещё не пройден, не могу его использовать